# Name of a dynamical system that extremizes an "action"?

Tags: terminology, dynamical-systems

In physics, the equations of motion of a physical system can be derived by minimizing/maximizing an "action", i.e. a functional of the path of the system:

$$J(x)= \int_a^bL(t,x(t),x'(t))dt$$

where $x:\mathbb R\to X$ is the motion over time, for some state space $X$.

**I assume that not all dynamical systems have the property that motion over time can be represented by the minimum of such a functional. Is there a name in mathematics for such systems?**

Comment: Invariant systems...also see the Principle of Least Action.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem

Comment: Lagrangian system...?

Comment: The terminology varies, as you can see from above. Sometimes people use variational as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A system of (differential) equations with a [variational principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_principle) is called a [variational system](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=variational+system) or sometimes a [Lagrangian system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_system)$^1$.

--

$^1$ Be aware that some systems in [Lagrangian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) are non-variational, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283238/2451) Phys.SE post.